# Xamarin (Mono.Android) запись в Excel файл потока данных для дальнейшей аналитики

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Есть IObservable поток данных (с bluetooth сканера), хотелось сохранять в Excel файл свойства полученных объектов.
Подскажите какую библиотеку для этого использовать?

Реализация сервиса будет в Mono.Android (Api V11)
использоваться сервис будет в netstandard2.1

Comment: а почему именно ексель? Ексель сложный формат. Сохраняй в CSV. А там уже импортируй его в ексель.

Comment: Можно и в CSV, есть ли готовые инструменты или просто форматную строку задать и сохранить?. И еше вопрос, если в режиме отладки запустить, то где будет находится программа и сохраненный файл на Android?

Comment: Если данные простые (без разделителей внутри данных, без переходов на следующую строку внутри данных) - то можешь генерировать CSV сам без всяких библиотек. Что до того где сохраненный файл - не в курсах.

Comment: Переход только 1 надо, в начале название столбцов описать потом данные через ; перечислить, думаю большего и не надо.

Comment: ничего не понял. Вобщем не важно. Еще раз: если нету символа-разделителя внутри любой из ячеек и если нету переходов на следующую строку внутри любой из ячеек - можешь генироировать CSV без всяких библиотек.

Comment: Хорошо попробую